# NSMutableArray to NSString conversion provides array instead of string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Here is my interface :

```
@interface AddRatingViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *categoryFromDb;
@end
```

The following code is in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Categories"];
[fetchRequest2 setPredicate:pre];

self.categoryFromDb = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest2 error:nil] mutableCopy];



if ([self.categoryFromDb count] > 0) {
    NSString *strUrl1 = [self.categoryFromDb valueForKey:@"rank1Img"];

}
```

`NSLog` shows that, the value of strUrl1 is :

```
(
"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=98E14854-7DA2-4B1F-9B0B-EEDCF3390DF3&ext=JPG"
)
```

But it should be only:

> assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=98E14854-7DA2-4B1F-9B0B-EEDCF3390DF3&ext=JPG

It seems that, the `strUrl1` is getting `NSArray` instead of string value. Now my question is that, how can I remove this `("` from the string
Or, 
How can I get string instead of array? 
Or any other suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of categoryFromDb belongs to the class "Categories". Can you try the following :-

```
NSString *strUrl1 = [((Categories *)[self.categoryFromDb lastObject]) valueForKey:@"rank1Img"];
```

assuming that you have a Categories class.

Comment: Your code really worked. Thank you so much. I don't have "Categories" class. So, I used: [([self.categoryFromDb lastObject]) valueForKey:@"rank1Img"]

Answer (score 1):

`executeFetchRequest:error:` returns an `NSArray` (as you seem to note). `[NSArray valueForKey:]` returns an `NSArray` made up of the results of each element's `rank1Img` result. If you only want one, then you either need to select a single element from `categoryFromDb` or from the result of `valueForKey:`. Usually you would use `lastObject` for this (when you believe there is only one element.

---

Edit: I note that several answers suggest using `objectAtIndex:0` to extract the sole element of an array. I recommend `lastObject`. If you are incorrect, and the array is empty, then `lastObject` will return `nil`. `objectAtIndex:0` throws an exception and likely crashes the program.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the 1st object in this case like below:

```
NSString *strUrl1 = [[self.categoryFromDb valueForKey:@"rank1Img"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following:

```
NSString * str = [[array valueForKey:@"rank1img"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call valueForKey on an `NSArray`, it iterates over all the items and gets the value for that key from each member. It's not exactly identical, but you can think of it like `map` in other languages. Your array is apparently one element long, so you can either keep the code as you have it and add `objectAtIndex:0` to `NSString *strUrl1 = [self.categoryFromDb valueForKey:@"rank1Img"];` to get the first element. If your processing differs if there is more than one element in the array, you'll need to check the length and then process it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The fetch request when executed yields the result in form of NSArray. You then use the key value coding which creates another array. 
If you had Person objects inside the NSArray like so,

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: person1, person2, person3,  nil];
```

Say, if you have a peroperty on the model Person, then the valueForKey:@"name" would yield a new array that contains name of each of those model.

```
NSArray *names = array[@"name"];
```

So, if you wish them to be joined, you would do it like this,

```
NSString *combinedName = [ array[@"name"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```